How to add audio files / where is the LMMS user content folder for My Samples in Windows?
I want to add audio files to use as samples in LMMS like kicks and snares. I expect them to be in My Samples:



I am unable to drag files or folders into LMMS directly. There are no context menus or buttons to add samples or directories.

By default you can add files and folders to %USERPROFILE%\Documents\lmms\samples\
If your username is TheSpiderman, it would most likely be located at:

C:\Users\TheSpiderman\Documents\lmms\samples\

If you add a file and a folder like so:



then they will shop up in LMMS (after you press the refresh button and expand your folder) like this:



This depends on the location of LMMS working directory which is configured in Edit > Settings > Paths (folder icon)


The path is stored in %USERPROFILE%\.lmmsrc.xml in the <paths/> tag as the workingdir attribute.
